classicmenu-indicator is not working in 24.04
classicmenu-indicator is not working in 24.04.
Trying to run it in terminal comes with the message (at the end):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/classicmenu_indicator/cmindicator.py", line 152, in __init__
    gettext.bind_textdomain_codeset(settings.GETTEXT_DOMAIN, 'UTF-8')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'gettext' has no attribute 'bind_textdomain_codeset'

An earlier answer suggests "unmarking line 152".
I need the exact commands to do that and test run.

Using your favorite editor from a commend line this is resolved by commenting out (add a # at beginning) of line 152 on "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/classicmenu_indicator/cmindicator.py"
Using vi.
If you don't raise privileges (sudo) it will not let you save the changes.
sudo vi /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/classicmenu_indicator/cmindicator.py

{type your password}
:152'rtn'     goes to line 152   
i             go to insert mode - doesn't print anything
#             add the # - you should see it being added
esc           leave insert mode - nothing printed
:wq'rtn'      write data and quit.

I have put return rtn in tics to highlight it as such - don't add the tics
esc is the escape key.
If you make a mistake hit esc esc :qrtn    and start again The :q doesn't save anything.
As python is interpretive I think you just just run the program after that. If it doesn't work try a reboot.
enjoy

Thanks it works. But came back with the following message:

/usr/bin/classicmenu-indicator:6: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

I exited python with ctrl z. Came back with "stopped jobs". typed ctrl z again, exited.

I edited the file back to what it was (deleted # at start of 152). classicmenu-indicator is in snap and so, it should get fixed. Hopefully. I just moved up to 24.04 and don't want to break anything :-).
