How can I get the Classic Menu Indicator app to work in Ubuntu 24.04?
I have Classic Menu Indicator installed but can not get it to open. I receive a notification saying the app is not sandboxed and I'm not sure if there is anything I can do? Doesn't this mean there is no snap for the app? So do I nee to wait for the author to supply a snap?

It looks like it's available in the official universe repositories so a snap would be unnecessary: https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/classicmenu-indicator Could you please add a screenshot of the notification in the question by Editing it?

Does it work after running the command sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0 ? If so, this will fix the issue permanently (otherwise, you need to run the command every time after starting the computer)

Although its in the official universe repositories (see above) there is a problem (if it is still there since I installed it) which can be fixed following details in the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525467/classicmenu-indicator-is-not-working-in-24-04/1525582#1525582

This question is similar to: classicmenu-indicator is not working in 24.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
